# Calling R function in C++, passing parameters

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am trying to call the `integrate()` function in R, and using it in my c++ code, because if coding my own numerical integration methods, the accuracy is not good as that in R. With the help of Rcpp, here is my code:

```
double den_cpp2 (NumericVector x, double theta){
int nx = x.size();
double val = 1;
for(int i=0;i<nx;i++){
  val = val * (2*x[i]/theta*(x[i]<=theta)+2*(1-x[i])/(1-theta)*(theta<x[i]));
}
return(val);
}
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector joint_cpp2 ( NumericVector theta,int n,NumericVector x, double a, double b){
int nt = theta.size();
//std::cout<<"nt = "<<nt<<"\n";
NumericVector val(nt);
//std::cout<<"val = "<<val<<"\n";
for (int j = 0; j < nt;j++){
  val[j] = den_cpp2(x,theta[j])*R::dbeta(theta[j],a,b,0);
}
return(val);
}
```

The above function `joint_cpp2` is what I'm trying to do numerical integration. Since the `integrate` function in R requires a vetorized function, so I wrote a vetorized version as it is. x is a sample generated to calculate the density in `den`, and a b are parameters with given values.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double callintegrate(Function f,double low, double up, int n, NumericVector x, 
                            double a, double b) {
    Function itgR("integrate");
    List res = itgR(f,low,up,n,x,a,b);
    //NumericVector res = f(x);
    return res["value"];
}
```

That is my method calling R function in C++. f is the function I want to integrate, low and up are the interval bounds, n,x,a,b are the parameters used in the function f.

So, I used in R:

```
n=1000
theta=0.01
a=b=0.5
x=Sample_x(n,theta)## a given function to generate samples
callFunction(joint_cpp2,0,1,n,x,a,b)
```

That works fast and fine in most cases. However, I met problems like:`extremely bad integrand behaviour`. I though maybe I should pass certain values to the `integrate` function. For example, rel.tol, the relative tolerance. Well, here comes the problem:
I tried to use :

```
double callintegrate(Function f,double low, double up, int n, NumericVector x, 
                            double a, double b,double rel.tol) {
    Function itgR("integrate");
    List res = itgR(f,low,up,n,x,a,b,rel.tol);
    //NumericVector res = f(x);
    return res["value"];
}
```

to pass the value of rel.tol to `integrate`. But, C++ does not accept the name style of rel.tol. I though, maybe I could ignore the name of variable, just plug in it as the right position in `integrate`. However, I don't know the right position as in :

```
integrate(f, lower, upper, ..., subdivisions = 100L,
          rel.tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.25, abs.tol = rel.tol,
          stop.on.error = TRUE, keep.xy = FALSE, aux = NULL)
```

I put the addition variable values of f in `...` ,then how can I tell the position of rel.tol.

Anyone can help me solve my problem? It is caused by the error :`extremely bad integrand behaviour`. I don't know how to deal with it. And it leads to another problem that how to pass values to the R function, when the naming conventions are different.

Comment: Calling an R function from C++ is still calling an R function.  If you want (numerical) integration, have you looked at [this Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NumericalMathematics.html) and particular the section in Integration?   I think there are a few cubature packages using Rcpp too...

Comment: I never found the document: this Task View. I will read it right now. However, just for the problem of passing parameter values to the R function, do you have any way to solve it?

Comment: The "dot" has a (very !!) different meaning in C++.  Call it `reltol` instead.

Comment: if I name it as 'reltol', how could the 'integrate()' in R, which I renamed as 'itgR', recognize it is exactly 'rel.tol'? That's where I'm confusing. Thank you.

Comment: This is not the place and time for a basic programming tutorial. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry to offend you. Maybe I lost myself somehow. I will dig it. Thank you and I still love your book.

Comment: Yes, do some reading, work through some of the examples in the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org) and it should all become clearer.  Final hint:  the name of the _calling_ variable does not have to equal the name of the _called_ variable, but both have to be valid within their context or languages.  Also consider rcpp-devel for more in-depth questions.  Good luck!